# Sumproduct using 2 criterias and on filtered values

Tags: excel, subtotal

I have the following source table

Date |  fruit  | veg

The user has previously filtered the date by month. In another table, I want to count the number of apples and tomatoes for example. To remove the invisible rows I use the SUBTOTAL function as

```
=(SUBTOTAL(102;OFFSET(limiter;ROW(limiter)-MIN(ROW(limiter));;1;1)))
```

where 'limiter' is the date range.

Then to count the number of apples in the fruit column , I use

```
= SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(102;OFFSET(limiter;ROW(limiter)-MIN(ROW(limiter));;1;1)) * Table!fruit = "apple"
```

and it works fine.

But, if I want to add in the vegetables criteria along with the fruit, the result is 0. I tried doing the sumproduct of fruit and veg first and then add the subtotal function but it gave a huge number.

Comment: I don't understand the use of SUBTOTAL here.  "To remove the invisible rows" - can you explain further?

Comment: We need a sample of what you have in "fruit" and "veg" columns in order to help any further....(single name? list of names? a number?)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a `pivot table`? (I strongly recommend you to)

Go to a new tab, select A1 and `insert`, `new pivot table`. You can put the `fruit` field in the column (probably `row labels` - my excel is in Portuguese =/). You would instantly have a table containing as first colum the list of existing fruits.

Then add the date to the body (probably `values`) of the pivot table and certify the type of value shown is `count`.

You would intantly get the count of all fruits.

The great advantage is that you can play around with this table as easily as dragging and dropping fields in columns, rows and body/values and instantly getting the results you want without having to figure out any formula issues.

Pivot tables also allow you to filter not only the date, but any other fields you wish.

Comment: The pivot table doesn't display filtered values using vba. And the table should be automatic.

Comment: @whatup, I think I don't understand your comment.where is the VBA part of your goal?